# Try/Except in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I am having difficulties with raising exceptions, for example:

```
import csv

o = open('/home/foo/dummy.csv', 'r') # Empty file!
reader = csv.reader(o, delimiter=';')
reader = list(reader)

try:
    for line in reader:
        print line[999] # Should raise index out of range!
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Basically csv.reader reads empty file, is converted to an empty list, and code above should print IndexError. But it does not.
Code below however raises perfectly:

```
print reader[0][999]

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since *reader* is an empty list, so your `for` loop is never executed. So, `line[999]` is not executed. That is why no exception is thrown.

As for the other code, the exception is thrown because you accessed the `0th` index of the empty list. Try just to access `reader[0]` and see whether you get an exception or not.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your file is empty - which means that your for loop doesn't ever execute.